# Changing default tooltip for boxplot outliers in ggiraph

Tags: r, ggplot2, tooltip, boxplot, ggiraph

In `geom_boxplot` of ggiraph by default the values are shown in tooltip for outliers. Is there a way to modify the tooltip for the outliers? We can change the tooltip for the plot using `tooltip` parameter. Is there a parameter to change the tooltip for the outlier also?

The following is my sample code:

```
 library(ggiraph)
 library(ggplot2)
 library(shiny)

    ui <- fluidPage(

      ggiraphOutput("plot")
    )

    server <- function(input, output, session){

      output$plot <- renderggiraph({
        p <- ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(x=cut, y=carat, tooltip=cut))+geom_boxplot_interactive()
        ggiraph(code = print(p))
      })

    }

    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I referred to the the documentation in [this](https://davidgohel.github.io/ggiraph/reference/geom_boxplot_interactive.html) link but it does not mention any such parameter. 
If parameter to change the outlier's tooltip does not exist can we change it using maybe some sort of js function?

Any type of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is `shiny` necessary here? I.e. I guess the problem/solution is similar when simply using `ggiraph` by itself.

Comment: Yes,  `shiny` is not necessary if there is a parameter to change the tooltip values. I thought in case that is not available, it might be possible using some kind of  javascript if it is a `shinyapp`.

Comment: You could turn off outliers and manually put them back with `geom_point_interactive` and choose your tooltip that way.

Comment: @Axeman Thanks. That would be a good option if there is no parameter to change the tooltip.